# Conducted Emissions for Ethernet ports

Tags: rf, noise, emc, termination, emissions

A device has a DC power port as well as 2 Ethernet ports. One of the ethernet ports supports PoE++. Basically, the EUT can be powered through PoE.
I have a question regarding Conducted Emissions measurements on said EUT.

For instance, when measuring the Emissions from the ethernet port 1, this is the setup that I envision. I believe that the DC port needs to be filtered and terminated using an LISN and the Ethernet port 2 needs to have an ISN and a 50ohms termination. Is that a correct assessment or I am missing the point?
[image]

Here is what I see in the standard, but it is not too clear to me. This is taken from ANSI C63.4.[image]

Comment: The ISN(s) will have a pass-through connection to auxiliary equipment (i.e. switch/PC/etc.), which you may want to show on the diagram for clarity. If the "AC-DC" is an adaptor supplied with the equipment, it will have an AC line LISN, i.e. swap the position of "AC-DC" and its LISN.  (Low voltage cables are not usually wired to a LISN, but such is useful for wired low voltage installations, automotive, etc.)

Comment: I completely agree with you, I updated the diagram.